# Strophe Ping Plugin Not responding

Tags: openfire, strophe

I am trying to add the Strophe ping plugin in to ping another user and respond with a pong, and then i know the user is connected.

But i am not sure how to get it working.

I read in the documentation an example, but it isnt working for me.

I just want to get some form of call back saying the other person is connected.

```
   conn.addHandler(pingHandler, "urn:xmpp:ping", "iq", "get");


 function pingHandler(ping) {
 var pingId = ping.getAttribute("1");
 var from = ping.getAttribute("from");
 var to = ping.getAttribute("to");
 var pong = $iq({type: "result", "to": from, id: pingId, "from": to});
 conn.send(pong);
  return true;
}
```

I also tried the method below, the method below will send out the Ping and called success that it is sent, but there is no respond in the pingHandler. Seems like it is sent, but it is not listened to/handled.

```
  conn.ping.addPingHandler( pingHandler );  

 function Onping(){


    var jid3="test4@macbook-pro.local"


     console.log("ping starts");
conn.ping.ping( jid3, success, error, timeout );


     function success(){
     console.log("ping sent");

     }
       function error(){
     console.log("ping Not sent");

     }
       function timeout(){
     console.log("ping Timeout");

     }





 }


            function pingHandler(ping) {
                  console.log("pong back");
     var pingId = ping.getAttribute("id");
     var from =  ping.getAttribute("from");
     var to = ping.getAttribute("to");
     var pong = $iq({type: "result", "to": from, id: pingId, "from": to});
     conn.send(pong);
      return true;
    }
```

Edit

```
SENT: <body rid='4132220829' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='a7411f98'><iq type='get' to='test4sdfsdfs@macbook-pro.local' id='1:ping' xmlns='jabber:client'><ping xmlns='urn:xmpp:ping'/></iq></body>

RECV: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' ack='4132220829'/>

RECV: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' ack='4132220829'><iq xmlns='jabber:client' type='result' id='1:ping' from='test4sdfsdfs@macbook-pro.local' to='test3@macbook-pro.local/a7411f98'/></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach a ping listener/handler upon connecting that sends the pong. Your listener responds to any pings sent to you. Your ping sender sets up a handler to handle to pong.

```
var onConn = function(){
    conn.ping.addPingHandler(onPing);
};

var onPing = function (iq) {
    conn.ping.pong(iq);
    return true;
};

var onPong = function(iq){
    //do whatever with response
    return false;
};

var sendPing = function(jid){
    conn.ping.ping(
        jid,
        function (iq) {onPong(iq);},
        function () { console.log('Failed!'); }, 
        3000);
};

sendPing('foo@jabberservername.com');
```

Comment: Hi Mark, i tried it, but it seems like i am not even receiving the ping in the first place, as i dont see the pong back in my console log in the user account that i am trying to ping.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a full example. Make sure you are adding the handler when you connect. Also check to make sure your server is configured to use ping.

Comment: Setting the xmpp.client.idle.ping to true right? Mine is set to true, i tested it,but it doesnt seem to be getting the pong back...it doesnt even seem to be receiving the ping in the first place... i added a console.log and RawInput/Ouput,and there is nothing when ping supposed to come thru. I am wondering if its something to do with my openfire. I am not having my connection disconnected as well at the time i set the idle disconnect to be.

Comment: I dont understand how to read the RawOutput i put them in the edit in my questions. Not sure why i have a RECV for the ping thats to me, but when i ping to an unexisting account. I am not trying to ping the server, i am trying to ping a specific client(user) to see if the are connected.

Comment: In the edit you added above, the response looks right. The SENT in your edit is your ping out, the last RECV is the pong back to you. The to and from is 'test4sdfsdfs@macbook-pro.local' and the pong is addressed to you. As for idle, I don't do anything with that. I will add your sid looks awfully suspicious, mine looks like a md5 hash or similar.

Comment: Em.... but 1 very odd thing, because when the user that i am trying to ping isnt connected, i still got the pong back from that user. And that 'test4sdfsdfs' user doesnt even exist in the server. So i am wondering if that is the server pinging me back instead of the user. Because when i have a user "supposed" to receive a ping, it actually doesnt show any RECV, but the "sender" does(assuming thats the pong from the server, instead of the client/user). And SID assuming thats under the "resource" from Openfire?

Comment: Could be. If you add the resource name to the jid (foo@jabberservername.com/resource), does it still respond? The SID should be a value created by the server that uniquely ids the user when they login (are you using bosh?). The resource is a name that you supply to id where the user is logged in from or whatever you may want to name it id where the user is at (desktop, website1, mars, etc).